# Is it possible to write HTML-withASP-withJavascript-withCSS in EMACS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, emacs, asp-classic

I am enjoying learning the EMACS text editor...but I can't help thinking that the HTML mode could use some work.

I am currently programming in Legacy ASP/Javascript/CSS/HTML and was wondering if there is a mode that works with this.  If possible, I was also hoping the mode wouldn't be from 10+ years ago or in a buggy state.

Thanks for your help!
Will

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[nXhtml](http://ourcomments.org/Emacs/nXhtml/doc/nxhtml.html) supports classic ASP JavaScript, is frequently updated and is not very buggy.  It has better ASP support (except debugging) than current versions of Visual Studio IMO; I just use VS2010 for server-side debugging when necessary.

Here are the relevant sections of my `.emacs`:

```
(load "autostart" t)
(eval-after-load "mumamo-fun"
  '(define-mumamo-multi-major-mode asp-html-mumamo-mode
     "Turn on multiple major modes for ASP with main mode `nxhtml-mode'.
This also covers inlined style and JavaScript."
     ("ASP Html Family" nxhtml-mode
      (mumamo-chunk-asp%
       mumamo-asp-chunk-inlined-script
       mumamo-chunk-inlined-script
       mumamo-chunk-style=
       mumamo-chunk-onjs=
       ))))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.inc$" . asp-html-mumamo-mode))

; XXX this is a total hack, see:
; http://www.mail-archive.com/nxhtml@lists.launchpad.net/msg00197.html
(defun tab-width-4 ()
  (setq tab-width 4))
(add-hook 'mumamo-after-change-major-mode-hook 'tab-width-4 t)
```

**Update:** For newer versions of nXhtml, you may need to change `mumamo-asp-chunk-inlined-script` to `mumamo-chunk-asp-server-script`.

(The last bit is necessary because the ASP code I'm working on assumes 4-space tabs; feel free to ignore it if this isn't a problem for you.)

If you have ASP that ends in anything other than `.asp` or `.inc`, you'll need to edit `auto-mode-alist` further.

Answer (score 1):

Since version 2.0 web-mode.el (available on http://web-mode.org) is compatible with ASPX. This major mode is also compatible with JSP and PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the [Emacs Emulation](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/emacs-emulation-extension-now-available/) for visual studio instead.